# How to add specific style to GWT DataGrid

Tags: java, gwt

I need add new style for some DataGrid rows, depending on variable.

For example:

```
table.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<Entry>() {
    @Override
    public String getStyleNames(Entry entry, int rowIndex) {
        return entry.isStyle() ? "newStyle" : null;
    }
});
```

"newStyle" is global css style.

The problem is style not applied to rows until i add `!important` to css definition.
But with `!important` i lost all default DataGrid styles and have only "newStyle".

**UPDATE:** css file

```
.newStyle {
    color : lightgray;
}
```

Comment: Please, add your css here! It seems the bad practice to use `!important`. See [What does !important mean in CSS?](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm) Also, see the [gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322779/gwt-theme-style-overrides-my-css-style) question. It may be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles) for the working solution. Copied for convenience:

> In short extend the `DataGrid.Style` (the goal is only to have a new
>   type, you don't have to add anything to it) and have your
>   `dataGridStyle` overridden method return your own subtype rather than
>   `DataGrid.Style` (and it'll work because of return-type covariance)

Comment: I saw this answer, but in that case when i'm using resource injecting i need to override every style.

Answer (score 1):

Change the definition of newstyle in your CSS file.  Usually it is better to make your CSS selector more specific rather than using `!important`.  Try combining the default DataGrid CSS names with yours.  For example: `dataGridHeader.newStyle {}`