# GWT DataGrid specific row needs add style

Tags: gwt, datagrid

is anyone have idea ,how to add specific style to GWT Datagrid?
I need to add style to specific row ( class="error") to show that row in red color.
More details:

Rendering the table using the GWT Datagrid. it has column called "type" . 
the type can have different values like " connected" ,"disconnected" ,"error".
if the type is error then i need to render row with different style( need to show text in the 
red color).

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you need and what you already have. Also post some code.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8899502/how-to-add-specific-style-to-gwt-datagrid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's [`RowStyles`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/RowStyles.html) for that exact purpose.

```java
grid.setRowStyles(new RowStyles<Row>() {
  @Override
  public String getStyleNames(Row row, int rowIndex) {
    return "error".equals(row.getType()) ? "error" : "";
  }
});
```