# GWT Grid Shows 2 lines as a borderline ,How can i replace it with 1 line

Tags: gwt

I am creating a simple DataGrid in GWT
It appeas fine and showing data , but the lines between rows or the border lines are double ,Can we change it to a single line 
border width is by default 1 , when i try to make border width as 0 , the border lines totally disappear and when i make it 1 , it shows double border lines , isnt there a way to smake the border line , a single line

Attached is the image of datagrid which is showing double border , please tell me a way to make it single border.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're showing two lines because you have borders around each cell and around the grid as well.

You should see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7394151/405492) for an explanation on how to override the default css of datagrids in GWT.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.css) is the default CSS for DataGrid that you should override. To avoid having double border, you should set only `border-right`, `border-left`, `border-top` or `border-bottom` attributes on your cells.

Comment: thanks , i see the default css , and added this whole in my application , can you just tell me which stylename i will apply to my widget , like , dataGrd.seStyleName("??");

Answer (score 0):

```
<g:Grid borderWidth="1" cellSpacing="0">
```

should do it. To adjust specific border css:

```
grid.setStyleName("yourSpecialBorderStyleName");
```

with css e.g.:

```
.yourSpecialBorderStyleName
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
}
```