# GWT DataGrid : "Unable to find ImageResource method value("cellTableLoading")" when overriding styles

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid

I tried to override styles for GWT DataGrid component like described here :

[DataGrid / CellTable styling frustration -- overriding row styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles)

My interface

```
public interface DataGridResources extends DataGrid.Resources {
@Source({ DataGrid.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "myDataGrid.css" })
DataGrid.Style dataGrid();
}

public static final DataGridResources dataGridResources =
```

Datagrid instance using Inteface

```
GWT.create(DataGridResources.class);

static {
    dataGridResources.dataGrid().ensureInjected();
}
```

...

```
dataGrid = new DataGrid<User>(10, dataGridResources);
```

But I get the following error :

```
Rebinding xxx.DataGridResources
-Invoking generator com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator
--Creating assignment for dataGrid()
---Creating image sprite classes
----Unable to find ImageResource method value("cellTableLoading") in xxx.DataGridResources : Could not find no-arg method named cellTableLoading in type xxx.DataGridResources
--Generator 'com.google.gwt.resources.rebind.context.InlineClientBundleGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'xxx.DataGridResources'
-Deferred binding failed for 'xxx.DataGridResources'; expect subsequent failures
```

Comment: See Thomas Broyer's answer in the SO question you linked. You need to also extend DataGrid.Style.

Comment: I tried replacing DataGrid.Style dataGrid(); by MyStyle dataGrid(); and public interface MyStyle extends DataGrid.Style { } but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works. Really.

```
public interface Resources extends DataGrid.Resources {

  interface Style extends DataGrid.Style { }

  @Source(value = {DataGrid.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "myDataGrid.css"})
  public Style dataGridStyle();
}
```

Also you don't need to call `ensureInjected()` since `DataGrid` will call it for you.

Anyway there is something wrong in the error log: it looks for `cellTableLoading` style which is not part of the `DataGrid.Resources` interface (is part of `CellTable.Resources`). Have you left some spurious CSS classes in `myDataGrid.css` that are not defined in the original interface?

Maybe you have moved from `CellTable` to `DataGrid` by simply renaming the css, but without changing the inner class names.

Comment: OK I got it. I thought there was a common CSS for cell components, hence I was using the CellTable CSS instead of DataGrid one. Now it works fine. Thanks a lot.