# How to set CSS Resource for DataGrid in UIBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, clientbundle

I have two questions.

Question #1. this question (post title) comes directly from the last comment from @Cataclysm on the first answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles):

> `dataGrid = new DataGrid<T>(pageSize, resource)`, how to set CSS
>   Resource for UIBinder ?

I am attempting to style a DataGrid defined in a UIBinder:

```
<g:south size="400">
    <c:DataGrid ui:field="documentDataTable" />
</g:south>
```

With this ClientBundle interface code:

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid.Resources;
import com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid.Style;

/**
 * Resources = "DataGrid.Resources"
 * Style     = "DataGrid.Style"
 * 
 * http://federico.defaveri.org/?p=157
 * https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144#c3
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles/7395175#comment26605442_7395175
 */
public interface CustomDataGridResource extends Resources {

    @Source({Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "css/CDD_DataGridStyle.css"})
    CustomStyle dataGridStyle();

    interface CustomStyle extends Style {
        String dataGridHeader();
    }
}
```

And `CDD_DataGridStyle.css`:

```
.dataGridHeader {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Using these references:

1. [DataGrid / CellTable styling frustration -- overriding row styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles)
2. http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html
3. http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.Style.html
4. http://crazygui.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-skin-a-gwt-celltable/
5. https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144#c3

From what I have understood from the answer to Reference 1, this resource style sheet is not "injected" like an ordinary client bundle, but rather should be passed in as a resource to a programmatically-instantiated data grid:

> "To construct your newly-styled datagrid all you need to do is:
>
> ```
> DataGridResource resource = GWT.create(DataGridResource.class);
> dataGrid = new DataGrid<T>(pageSize, resource)"
> ```

Oddly, although I have a reference to the `DataGrid @UIField`, there does not appear to be any method in the `DataGrid.java` [API documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.html) to "set" the resource (Hence the question as a repost of the last comment on this question about a `DataGrid` already defined in UIBinder -- [DataGrid / CellTable styling frustration -- overriding row styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394151/datagrid-celltable-styling-frustration-overriding-row-styles/7395175#comment26605442_7395175)).

---

Question #2: What is the difference between `DataGrid` vs. `CellTable`, and which is the correct implementation syntax?

Why does the Google GWT API documentation for `DataGrid.java` (Reference 2) only detail a `CellTable` instantiation programmatically? I understand that `DataGrid.java` extends `AbstractCellTable.java` but why not use any of the seven `DataGrid` constructors in the API Example code?

To make matters more confusing, References 4 and 5 suggest that my client bundle interface should be extending `CellTable.Resources`, while Reference 1 suggests extending `DataGrid.Resources` (see also this link: http://federico.defaveri.org/?p=157).

I tried adapting the the "After" code example from the last post (#13) from [Reference 5](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144#c3) but the nested interfaces threw an error:

```
public interface NxoCellTableResources extends CellTable.Resources {
    public interface NormalStyle extends CellTable.Style {}

    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "NxoCellTable.css" })
    public NormalStyle cellTableStyle();
}

public interface NxoCellTableThinResources extends CellTable.Resources {
    public interface ThinStyle extends CellTable.Style {}

    @Source({ CellTable.Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "NxoCellTable.css", "NxoCellTableThin.css" })
    public ThinStyle cellTableStyle();
}
```

In summary, I am looking for the simplest way to style all elements in a DataGrid defined in a UIBinder with a clear explanation of which Resource syntax to use (DataGrid vs. CellTable). I am open to removing the reference from UIBinder and inserting programmatically into the view if necessary, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**

Everything you said, is correct.

Make sure you pass `provided=true` to your DataGrid's `UiField`:

```
@UiField(provided = true)
DataGrid<MyDTO> dataGrid;
```

Then in the constructor you would create the `DataGrid` like this:

```
public MyView() {
   CustomDataGridResource resource = GWT.create(CustomDataGridResource.class);
   resource.dataGridStyle().ensureInjected();
   dataGrid = new DataGrid<MyDTO>(pageSize, resource)"
   binder.createAndBindUi(this);
}
```

Make sure you call `ensureInjected()` on the style. 
Also if you have an `Inject` on your constructor. 
You can pass the CustomDataGridresource and `GWT.create()` will be automatically called:

```
@Inject
public MyView(CustomDataGridResource resource) {
   resource.dataGridStyle().ensureInjected();
   dataGrid = new DataGrid<MyDTO>(pageSize, resource)"
   binder.createAndBindUi(this);
}
```

**Question 2:**
Regarding the difference between `CellTable` and `DataGrid` refer to this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/PBhu6RtP4G8

Basically if you use `LayoutPanels` `DataGrid` is a good fit as it contains fixed headers and a scrollable content area. `CellTable` will also work with `FlowPanel` and normal `Panels`.

Answer (score 1):

GWT has this documented [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Share_resource_instances).

A good example can be found [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/24/gwt-uibinder-passing-objects-to-widgets/).

Comment: The GWT documentation is clunky, obtuse, and almost 5 years old... [GWT IS DEAD](http://www.guynirpaz.com/2012/04/28/gwt-is-dead/)